# Parallel algorithms and data structures

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, parallel-processing

Inkeeping with my interests in algorithms (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654771/algorithms-and-data-structures-that-are-not-mainstream-closed)), I would like to know if there are (contrary to my previous question), algorithms and data structures that *are* mainstream in parallel programming. It is probably early to ask about mainstream parallel algos and ds, but some of the gurus here may have had good experiences/bad experiences with some of them.

**EDIT**: I am more interested in successful practical applications of algos and ds than in academic papers.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of Google's whitepapers, especially but not exclusively ones linked from [this page](http://research.google.com/pubs/DistributedSystemsandParallelComputing.html), describe successful practical applications of parallel distributed computing and/or their DS and algorithmic underpinnings. For example, [this paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1328671.1328673) deals with modifying a DBMS's data structures to extract intra-transaction parallelism; [this one](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html) (and some others) introduces the popular `mapreduce` architecture, since implemented e.g. in [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/core/); [this one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4284890&isnumber=4284553) is about highly parallelizable approximate matrix factoring suitable for use in "kernel methods" in machine learning; etc, etc...

Answer (score 8):

Maybe, I totally miss the point, but there are a ton of mainstream parallel algos and data structures, e.g. [matrix multiplication](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node45.html#SECTION02560000000000000000), [FFT](http://www2.cs.uh.edu/~mirkovic/fft/parfft.htm), [PDE](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node10.html#SECTION02241000000000000000) and [linear equation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node90.html#SECTION03480000000000000000) solvers, integration and simulation ([Monte-Carlo](http://www.phy.hr/~laci/para/mc/mc.html) / [random numbers](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node116.html#SECTION04200000000000000000)), [searching](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node10.html#SECTION02243000000000000000) and [sorting](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node127.html#SECTION04340000000000000000), and so on. Take a look at the [Designing and Building Parallel Programs](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/) or [Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.pearsoned.co.uk/Bookshop/detail.asp?item=100000000052063). And then there is [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html) and the like. What are you after?

Answer (score 4):

Sorting:

- [Standard Template Library for Extra Large Data Sets](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/)
- [Sort Benchmark](http://sortbenchmark.org/)